# How to link printer of other wifi into local network without opening serious security hole?

Tags: networking

I have an office in a large collaboratory space with other small companies. The colab space has its own wifi with a printer that everyone can use. To use it, one has to connect to their wifi though.
Its annoying to always have to switch networks when I want to print something. I wonder if there is an easy way to link just that printer into my own local network, without creating a trivial security hole in our own network? Something like taking a raspberry pi, connecting it by ethernet to my own network and by wifi to the collaboratory space. But how would I need to configure the raspberry pi then to link in the printer and not allow any other kind off traffic through?

by the way, I can't connect to the colab network in any other way other than wifi

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you connect to the printer when you are connected to there wifi (e.g. protocol, ports, ip-address, etc.)

Comment: A solution to solve this problem will require enterprise hardware and knowledge which turns this question outside of the scope of SuperUser. There are Stack Exchange sites that can help you here though. See also: https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @bey0nd when I'm conntected to he wifi the printer just appears. Chrome seems to find it automatically (I didn't need to install any drivers)

Comment: @LPChip last time I asked something similar on serverfault they told me it's off topic because I didn't run a Enterprise grade setup and should go to superuser instead :/

Comment: Also I don't need enterprise security in this regard - I just don't want to open a trivial hole (like I don't want my NAS suddenly be visible to other users in the colab wifi or something like that)

Comment: It is possible via a router and DNAT port redirects or running [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) and using it's [p910nd print server](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/print_server/p910ndprinterserver). You'll need to manually forward the ports and their protocols to the IP of your PC that's behind your router, with the protocol and ports required varying by manufacturer _(for example, for Canon's MF8380, the required ports are `137`, `138`, `139`, `161`, `3702`, `8610`, `8611`, `8612`, `8613`)_

Comment: @ JW0914 sounds interesting. Do I need to create a network bridge between the ethernet and the wifi adapters? If I just connect ethernet to my local network and wifi to the other network (without any other settings), does that in itself already create some open routes and if so, what do I need to close them?

Comment: @user1282931 The most secure way of doing this is to configure a vlan on the router for interfacing with the printer, and then either manually configure the routing between LAN and vLAN on the router or manually assign the PC an additional vLAN IP within the PC's OS _(on Windows, you could also use OpenVPN's TAP adapter to create a vlan interface on Windows, which is the only way to create a vlan interface on Windows)_.  Using OpenWrt for all of this would be the most efficient, especially if using an embedded SBC device like a [Pi](https://openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi_foundation/raspberry_pi)

Comment: On a simpler note, do you have a wired network and does the printer have a wired port? Could you just run a cable and connect it to your wired network, leaving the WiFi as is?